# How do I pass a data variable from one view to the other?

Tags: vue.js

So all I am trying to do is pass the variable called `localUser` from the `Login` view after the `Login` view changes to the route `Home` with `router.push("Home");` and then I am trying to get `localUser` value in the `Home` view and its components.

---

**What I've tried**:
I've been trying all kinds of solutions from other stack questions, but I can't make it work which I'm sure is my fault here. I have even tried passing the data with props because I am really stuck and don't know what to do anymore.

p.s. Please forgive my "newbness", because this is my third day taking on my first JS Framework ever.

---

View **"Login"**

```js
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <div class="upperNav">
    <img class="v" alt="Vue logo" src="../assets/cbsc3-n4s6k.svg">
      <div v-if="localUser !== ''">
        <span>{{ localUser.displayName }}</span>
        <img class="pImg" :src="localUser.photoURL" alt="profile picture"/>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>

import router from '../router'

import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld.vue';

export default {
  name: 'Login',
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      localUser: '',
      profileVisible: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {

    GoogleSignIn: function (event) {
      var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
      firebase.auth().languageCode = 'en';


      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged( (user) => {
        if (user) {
          // If already signed in.
          console.log(user.displayName);
          this.localUser = user;
          console.log("Localuser:" + this.localUser.displayName)
          router.push("Home");
        } else {
          // If no one is signed in.
          firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {

                console.log("Logged in.");
                var token = result.credential.accessToken;
                var user = result.user;
                this.localUser = user;
                console.log("Localuser:" + this.localUser)

          }).catch(function(error) {
                var errorCode = error.code;
                var errorMessage = error.message;
                var email = error.email;
                // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
                var credential = error.credential;
                console.log(errorMessage);
          });

        }
      });
      let self = this;
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log("Mounted");
    this.GoogleSignIn();
  }
}
</script>
```

View **"Home"**

```js
<template>
  <div class="about">
    <h1>{{ localUser.displayName }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>


<script>

export default {
  name: 'Home',
  props: ['localUser'],
  components: {

  },
  data: function() {
    return {

    }
  },
  methods: {

  },
  mounted() {

  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to introduce an event bus, or something like `vuex`, just write it to the sessionStorage:

```
window.sessionStorage.setItem('localUser', JSON.stringify(this.localUser))
```

then in `Home`:

```
computed: {
 localUser: {
   get: function() {
     return JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem('localUser'))
   }
 }
}
```

and now `Home` can use `this.localUser` in the script and `localUser` in the SFC template.

Comment: Sorry but it refuses to work; I either get undefined, or the variable turns completely empty.